# Cannot access files in website. (net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net, iis-8.5

I installed asp.net project on IIS8.5.

But the site is missing files such as images and css even there are existing.
Please help me why.

[image]

Comment: Internal Server error could mean lots of things. It's just a message to the browser that the server code crashed in some way. I suggest checking the Windows Event Log to begin with, to see if there are more detailed error messages posted there.

Comment: Does your IIS process have access to the files? Usually unhandled exceptions are logged server side, have you seen logs in the server event log?

Comment: Yes, I saw log
500 GET /image/cdfour_4.png - HTTP/1.1
500 GET /image/cdfive_5.png - HTTP/1.1

Comment: that looks like an IIS logfile entry rather than an exception report in the Windows Event Viewer? Where did you look for the log, specifically?

Comment: It seems there are something wrong with your url part for the css and image file.I suggest you could check the css file and image file's path is right. If possbile please post the details codes about how you add these reference in your asp.net application.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I solved the problem.
I removed following tag in web.config file
<staticContent>
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
 </staticContent>
Now, It works well.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, WarLord, Thanks for the update. After removing the tag <staticContent> the issue got fixed.